# Is there a way to give condition to a <Link>?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

the page shows a list of elements got from a db; about the last displayed element, clicking on it,  i need to Link to '/upload' if it displays "Carica Referto", or Link to /consensi/{this.$state.item.hash_consenso}'if it displays "Leggi Referto"

I have tried to put If and Else but it responds with an error because they are not defined in react-router-dom (Link is defined)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class ConsensiItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            item: props.item
        }
    }  

    render() {
        return (
            <li className="registration-form">
                <ul className="container">
                    <li className="registration-form">Paziente :{this.state.item.giver}</li>
                </ul>
                <ul className="container">
                    <li className="registration-form">Data inizio consenso :{this.state.item.data_inizio}</li>
                </ul>
                <ul className="container">
                    <li className="registration-form">Data Fine Consenso :{this.state.item.data_fine}</li>
                </ul>
                <ul> 
                    Tipo consenso :
                    <Link to= {'/upload'}>{this.state.item.diritti}</Link>
                </ul>
                <br/>
                <br/>
            </li>
        )
    }
}

export default ConsensiItem
```

Comment: You need `<Link to={ this.state.item.diritti == "Carica Referto" ? "/upload" : "/consensi/" + this.state.item.hash_consenso }>`

Comment: You can also set a variable in `render()` before returning the JSX: `var upload = this.state.item.diritti == "Carica Referto";` then use conditional rendering: `{ upload && <Link to="/upload">...</Link> }` followed by `{ !upload && <Link ...> }`

Comment: Turn your logic around: 'if x is the case, render <Link to="upload">, else render <Link to="somewhere else">`. Your UI should render exactly only what the state says should be there - the logic should happens before the UI gets returned. Not as part of the UI's behaviour.

Comment: Thank you Chris G! it worked

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** There is no such option as to use `if` inside `{}` in react jsx.
Most likely it is because you need operator inside `{}` to return something. `&&`, `||` and `?` operators always return something and you can safely use them. While `if` statement doesn't return anything.

Please read react docs about [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator).

React offers you a few ways of conditional rendering:

#### [Inline If-Else with Conditional Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator)

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const isCondition = true;
  const hash = 'hash';
  return (
     <Link to={isCondition ? '/upload' : `/consensi/${hash}`}>text</Link>
  )
}
```

#### [Using if statement](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

```
function MyComponent() {
  const isCondition = true;
  const hash = 'hash';
  if (isCondition) {
    return <Link to= {'/upload'}></Link>;
  }
  return <Link to={`/consensi/${hash}`}>text</Link>;
}
```

#### [Inline If with Logical && Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const isCondition = true;
  const hash = 'hash';
  return (
     <div>
        {isCondition && <Link to= {'/upload'}>text</Link>}
        {!isCondition && <Link to={`/consensi/${hash}`}>text</Link>}
     </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Note that that "if condition" has two options. One returning a full `Link` component, and one (not listed) that only creates the `to` argument and then returns `<Link to={to}/>`. And of course, there is a final unlisted option, and that's a mapping object: `<Link to={mapped[this.state.blah] || this.state.blah}/>` with a global-to-the-module `const mapped`.